# Google Sheets Filter: OR not working on match functions

Tags: google-sheets

I have been working with the filter function in google sheets for a few months now and really like them, they're very powerful. Now recently, I wanted to try using the match function inside the filter function to find intersects between lists.

This I'm having some trouble with though, below is part of a filter function I'm trying to make but it doesn't seem to be working. Separately the match functions work fine in the filter but strung together with an OR (+) it doesn't work. It only returns the first match's results if that row's value also has true in the C column.

This might not be super clear, but maybe some of you have seen this before.

Here is an [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rN4EdTE03ZJ81n2p-QhYgVW28TbdoliMBIRfEPJjT3Q/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=FILTER($C$6:$E,
  (
    MATCH($C$6:$C, FILTER('Other Tab'!$A$3:$A, 'Other Tab'!$B$3:$B), false) +
    MATCH($C$6:$C, FILTER('Other Tab'!$A$3:$A, 'Other Tab'!$C$3:$C), false)
  )
)
```

I tried stripping away most of the filter function except for the troubling part (the example I posted above).

I tried putting the other match first.

I tried mixing the match functions with other conditions and this combination is the only one giving me so much trouble.

Comment: @ErikTyler, I added a link to a sheet with an example.

Comment: @ErikTyler, Your solution works for my basic example but that was just a simplified version of my intended function. I updated the sheet to show the full (or at least a bigger part) of my function.

I have also added an explanation of my intended result.

Comment: @ErikTyler, I realize that. That's why I gave the simplified version. I'm not really looking for someone to just give me a working formula. I'm just wondering why the OR gate doesn't work with the MATCH function. If I know why that doesn't work, I can continue on my own.